# Why my output is "()" and how can i fix it?

Tags: file, haskell, output

I do work with text rotate from a txt file, I'm stuck on the simplest thing - output back to the same file. At the end of the program, “()” appears in the test file (output.txt). I know I need to rewrite `main2` somehow, but I don’t know how exactly. There is problem with side effects, I think. So, what to do? I will be happy to get your help

```
import System.IO

getPixel :: [[Char]] -> Int -> Int -> Char
getPixel img x y
  | x >= 0 && x < width && y >= 0 && y < height = img !! y !! x
  | otherwise = ' '
  where
    height = length img
    width = length $ head img

rotate :: Double -> (Double, Double) -> (Double, Double)
rotate a (x, y) = (x * cos a + y * sin a, -x * sin a + y * cos a)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    output <- main2
    writeFile "output.txt" (show output)

main2 :: IO ()
main2 = do
    image <- lines <$> readFile "input.txt"
    mapM_ putStrLn $ do
        y <- [0 .. 30]
        return $ do
            x <- [0 .. 40]
            let (x', y') = rotate (pi/3) (x-5, y-1)
            return $ getPixel image (floor x') (floor y')
```

Comment: Since `main2` has type `IO ()`, that means that `output` in `output <- main2` will be `()`, hence `show output` will be `"()"`.

Comment: Rewrite `mapM_` to `mapM`, and change the signature to `main2 :: IO [Char]`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Did you test this proposed fix? It doesn't look right to me.

Comment: @DanielWagner: ah yes, forgot the `putStrLn` in the `mapM`, well. it is a bit "odd" to use `putStrLn` here. You are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At the end of the program, `()` appears in the test file (`output.txt`)

Well the reason it writes `()` is because the signature of `main2` is `main2 :: IO ()`. This means that `output` in `output <- main2` will be the [*unit type* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type), and thus `show ()` will return the string `"()"`.

But you actually do not need to use `mapM_` here in the first place. You can make a function that will, for a given `[[Char]]` generate a list of chars, for example:

```
rotateImg :: (Int -> Int -> Char) -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [[Char]]
rotateImg getPix ys xs = [
    [ getPix (floor x) (floor y) | x' <- xs, let (x, y) = rotate (pi/3) (fromIntegral (x'-5), fromIntegral (y'-1)) ]
    | y' <- ys
  ]
```

So then we can define in the `main` a function that reads then image info, rotates the image, and finally writes the rotated image to a file (or prints it to the stdout):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    image <- lines <$> readFile "input.txt"
    let image2 = rotateImg (getPixel image) [0..30] [0..40]
    writeFile "output.txt" (unlines output)
```

Answer (score -2):

Change `main2 :: IO ()` to `main2 :: [Char]`. Oh and `mapM_` to `mapM`.

I can't see anything else off, so that should fix it.